# Не работает сессия в HTTP

Tags: сессия

На сайте имеется несколько страниц которые загружаются по HTTP, в которых массив $_SESSION не передается, в то время когда загруженные страницы по HTTPS в $_SESSION есть все данные.

В чем может быть проблема? session_start(); прописан в самом начале на всех страницах.

Comment: У HTTP и HTTPS сессии раздельные, всё просто

Comment: Как можно решить проблему? Нужно что бы пользователь также был авторизирован и на страницах загруженных по HTTP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/441496/5441700 посмотрите. Может есть толковый вариант.

Comment: @Юрий вариант прекратить использование HTTP не рассматривается? :)